# Get value of selected option based on attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an admin panel. When the admin changes a check box and then clicks the apply button It should get the selected options from the row that is associated with the user whose information I would like to update.

The code I have just returns undefined when the apply button is selected. Any insight would be appreciated.

[Admin Panel Image](https://gyazo.com/78197abff94b568e207a2c5eb5e40629)

```
Template.userTable.events({
"click button" : function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // We get the id of the user whos information we want to update.
    var selectedUser = $(event.target).attr('data-id');

    var profileUpdate = {
        'profile.maxPosts' : $('#maxPosts option:selected').find("[data-id='"+selectedUser+"']").val();
    };

    Meteor.users.update({_id:selectedUser}, {$set: profileUpdate});

}
});
```

**html**

```
<template name="userTable">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Username
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Faction
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Admin Permissions
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Max Orders
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {{#each users}}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{_id}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{profile.name}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{profile.faction}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="isAdmin">
                            <option data-id="{{_id}}" value="true" {{isEqual profile.isAdmin true}}>Yes</option>
                            <option data-id="{{_id}}" value="false" {{isEqual profile.isAdmin false}}>No</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="maxPosts">
                            <option data-id="{{_id}}" value="0" {{isEqual profile.maxPosts 0}}>0</option>
                            <option data-id="{{_id}}" value="10" {{isEqual profile.maxPosts 10}}>10</option>
                            <option data-id="{{_id}}" value="20" {{isEqual profile.maxPosts 20}}>20</option>
                            <option data-id="{{_id}}" value="30" {{isEqual profile.maxPosts 30}}>30</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button data-id="{{_id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Apply Changes</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </template>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just wrap each row's selects/buttons in a form?

Comment: Would that address the issue?

Comment: By doing it like that you wouldn't have to do some complex logic to find the data for each user, you could just intercept the form submit event and from there get the values easily. I've never worked with Meteor before, but when I made a similar application that's what I did, and it was easier to manage.

Comment: That's true, I only tend to think of forms in the context of logins and email forms so I overlooked its application in this context.